# How to calculate the neighborhood of a graph with order 1.5?

Tags: graph-theory, igraph, sna

I have a graph object `g` and would like to create a subgraph `g_sub` of the neighborhood of a set of vertices `v_matches` in `g`, with `order` 1.5.

In other words I want to find which vertices are connected to `v_matches` (order 1), and which vertices are connected to the order==1 vertices *if and only if* these are also connected to the `v_matches` vertices.

In non-technical terms I want to find 'friends of friends (order 2), provided that these friends are also my friends (order 1.5)'. I cannot find a way to do this easily in `igraph`.

The code I have written calculates order 2 neighborhood of `v_matches`, but I want it to calculate order 1.5. Any help is very much appreciated.

`v_matches <- which(V(g)$SomeVertexAttribute==SomeValue)`

`g_sub <- induced.subgraph(graph=g,vids=unlist(neighborhood(g,order=2,nodes=v_matches)))`

UPDATE: Here is a function and some code I wrote to convert an `order=2` subgraph to `order 1.5`. However, I am not convinced it is working properly.

```
Order2ToOrder1.5 <- function(g_sub,categoryValue) {
  # get the new indexes of the 'ego' sites for the subgraph
  matches_subgraph_gsub <- which(V(g_sub)$`Categorical 1`==categoryValue)
  # get the edge list of the subgraph
  edgelistTemp <- get.edgelist(g_sub)
  # get unique "from" values
  uniqueFrom <- unique(edgelistTemp[,1])

  badVerts <- c() # yes, I know it is bad form to append to a vector using a for loop...
  for (i in 1:length(uniqueFrom)){
    # we find the immediate neighbours of each vertice
    tempGraph <- as.vector(neighborhood(graph=g_sub,order=1,nodes=uniqueFrom[i])[[1]])
    # if the neighbourhood does not contain one of the 'ego' sites (i.e. in matches_subgraph_gsub), then we flag this vertex for deletion
    matchTemp <- match(tempGraph,matches_subgraph_gsub)
    if (length(which(is.na(matchTemp)))==length(matchTemp)) {badVerts <- append(badVerts,uniqueFrom[i])}
  }

  # now we can delete these from the subgraph:
  g_return <- delete.vertices(g_sub,badVerts)
}

categoryValue <- 21
matches <- which(V(g)$`Categorical 1`==categoryValue)
g_sub <- induced.subgraph(graph=g,vids=unlist(neighborhood(graph=g,order=2,nodes=matches)))

# We can use the new function to convert from order2 to order1.5:
g_sub_1.5 <- Order2ToOrder1.5(g_sub,categoryValue)
```

Comment: If you want friends' friends that are also friends of yours, then they'll be in the 1-neighborhood.

Comment: Hi Gabor, thanks for the reply. This makes sense, however my understanding is that the 1-neighborhood is simply the immediate alters of ego. Are you saying that the 1-neighborhood also includes the edges between the alters of the alters of ego, provided that these are also alters of ego? 

For example, the middle diagram in this picture: http://people.oii.ox.ac.uk/hogan/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Screen-shot-2010-11-25-at-15.40.13.png

Comment: The 1-neighborhood includes all immediate neighbors and all edges between them.

Comment: Oh, that's really great to know. Thanks for clarifying this. Whilst I am here, also wanted to say a huge thanks for the igraph package - it is phenomenal work - and much appreciated in the computational sociology community :)